# Mostrar datos de una consulta SQL en múltiples tablas HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
$stmt = $conn->query(
    "SELECT
        lista.nombre AS nomLista,
        candidato.nombre AS nomCandidato,
        partido.nombre AS nomPartido
    FROM
        candidato
    INNER JOIN lista ON lista.id = candidato.id_lista
    INNER JOIN partido ON partido.id = candidato.id_partido
    INNER JOIN region ON region.id = candidato.id_region
    WHERE region.nombre = 'Metropolitana'"
);
```

cuyos resultados he podido mostrar en la siguiente tabla:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Candidato</th>
        <th>Partido</th>
        <th>Lista</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php $records = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); ?>
    <?php foreach($records as $row): ?>
    <tr>
    <?php echo "<td>".$row['nomCandidato']."</td>"; ?>
    <?php echo "<td>".$row['nomPartido']."</td>"; ?>
    <?php echo "<td>".$row['nomLista']."</td>"; ?>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

y se ve asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo la forma en que tengo que mostrar los datos es asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver en este último mockup, lo que busco no es mostrar una sola tabla por región, si no poder mostrar tantas tablas como listas haya en la región. Lo he intentado pero sin éxito, y de paso decir que aun estoy aprendiendo a usar los arrays en PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma de hacerlo (bastante riesgosa), sería verificando dentro del `foreach` cuando te encuentres en el primer valor de cada lista para iniciar una nueva tabla. Pero, si los valores de `nomLista` **no están correctamente ordenados**,sería un código desastroso. Aparte de eso, supone leer y releer los datos... A no ser que uses un Iterador, pero eso ya son palabras mayores.

Pero, ¿por qué no traer los datos ya estructurados e imprimir las tablas de una manera limpia y sin riesgo de errores?

Desde la consulta, puedes crear una estructura en forma de JSON con este aspecto:

```
[
   {
      "lista":"A",
      "candidatos":[
         {
            "nomCadidato":"Jhon",
            "nomPartido":"Uno de A"
         },
         {
            "nomCadidato":"Marta",
            "nomPartido":"Dos de A"
         }
,
         {
            "nomCadidato":"Santiago",
            "nomPartido":"Tres de A"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "lista":"B",
      "candidatos":[
         {
            "nomCadidato":"Juana",
            "nomPartido":"Uno de B"
         },
         {
            "nomCadidato":"Pedro",
            "nomPartido":"Dos de B"
         }

      ]
   }
]
```

Tenemos un array de listas y dentro de cada lista un array de candidatos.

Esto es relativamente fácil, y lo es aún más desde MySQL 8+ que te permite crear objetos JSON con relativa facilidad ([ver el Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html)).

Dado que no sé si tienes MySQL 8+, escribiré la consulta concatenando, para producir una estructura como el ejemplo de más arriba, verás que no es tan complicado.

Vamos con la consulta:

```
$stmt = $conn->query(
"SELECT
    CONCAT(
        '{\"lista\":\"',
        lista.nombre,
        '\",\"candidatos\":[',
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            CONCAT(
                '{\"nombre\":\"',
                candidato.nombre,
                '\",\"partido\":\"'
                ,partido.nombre,'\"}'
            )
        ),']}'
    ) AS json 
FROM
        candidato
    INNER JOIN lista ON lista.id = candidato.id_lista
    INNER JOIN partido ON partido.id = candidato.id_partido
    INNER JOIN region ON region.id = candidato.id_region
    WHERE region.nombre = 'Metropolitana'
    GROUP BY lista.nombre");
```

Sí las listas tienen un ID es mejor que cambies esto `GROUP BY lista.nombre` por `GROUP BY lista.laColumnaID`, así aprovechas los índices.

Ahora vamos a ejecutar esa consulta, leeremos sus filas y crearemos las tablas de una forma limpia.

Me permitiré trabajar con `sprintf` y sus parientes, así, haremos todo dentro de un mismo bloque PHP, evitaremos la confusa mezcla de bloques PHP / HTML y reutilizaremos código, para tales fines, definiremos algunas variables e iremos cambiando los marcadores... es algo parecido a lo que hacen las plantillas como Twig u otros.

Pondré algunos comentarios en el código.

```
#Variable para concatenar todo
$html="";
#Cabeceras de las tablas
$heads=array('CANDIDATO','PARTIDO');
#Plantilla de la tabla, una %s para thead y otra para tbody
$table="<table>%s%s</table>";
#Plantilla para las filas / celdas
$trows="<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>";
#Creamos el thead que siempre es el mismo
$thead=sprintf("<thead>%s</thead>",vsprintf($trows,$heads));
#Plantilla para el tbody
$tbody="<tbody>%s</tbody>";

#Obtenemos los datos. OJO no se usa fetchAll

while ( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    /*
      Esto crea un objeto con los datos de la columna json
      que es la columna que creamos concatenando en la
      instrucción SQL.
      NÓTESE: que se usa la notación de objeto ->
      para obtener los datos, lo mismo ocurre
      en el foreach interior, todo es un objeto aquí
    */
    $obj=json_decode($row['json']);
    #Vamos creando cada tabla usando las plantillas
    $html.=sprintf("<h2>Lista %s</h2>",$obj->lista);
    $currentRows="";
    foreach ($obj->candidatos as $c){
        $currentRows.=sprintf($trows,$c->nombre,$c->partido);
    }
    $html.=sprintf($table,$thead,sprintf($tbody,$currentRows));
}

#Imprimimos todas las tablas

echo $html;
```

Así tu problema debería quedar resuelto. Cualquier duda, pregunta en comentarios, al pie de esta respuesta.  **Soy humano, no soy una IA**.

Comment: ya probe la solucion que propones, sigo teniendo una sola tabla, soy nuevo en el uso del formato json pero guiandome por el ejemplo que pusiste de la estructura que deberia tener el json y comparandolo con lo que me muestra el print_r veo que la estructura generada no es la misma que la del ejemplo.

Comment: para ser mas concreto lista me aparece una sola vez en el print_r cuando deberian haber mas de uno

Comment: @Eipo sí, perdona, es que olvidé algo muy importante en la consulta, tienes que agregar al final **`GROUP BY lista.nombre`** para que agrupe los datos por cada lista. Ahora edito para que veas cómo debe quedar la consulta.

Answer (score 2):

Una forma que se me ocurre es dividir todas las listas en sub-arrays diferentes:

```php
$data = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) { // <-- Cambiar fechAll por fetch
    $lista = $row['nomLista'];
    $data[$lista][] = $row;
}
```

Hasta este punto, `$data` tendrá esta estructura:

```php
[
  'A' => [
      ['nomLista'=>'A', 'nomCandidato'=>'Candidato 1', 'nomPartido'=>'Partido1'],
      ['nomLista'=>'A', 'nomCandidato'=>'Candidato 2', 'nomPartido'=>'Partido2'],
      // ...
  ]
  'B' => [
      ['nomLista'=>'B', 'nomCandidato'=>'Candidato 3', 'nomPartido'=>'Partido3'],
      // ...
  ]
  // ...
]
```

Ahora es solo cuestión de imprimir cada uno de los subarrays individualmente, para ello lo mejor es crear una función que imprima tantas tablas como cantidad de subarrays que haya en `$data`.

```php
function printTable(array $array): void {
    ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Candidato</th>
            <th>Partido</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <?php
        foreach($array as $row) {
            ?>
            <td><?php echo $row['nomCandidato'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['nomPartido'];?></td>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}

// Y se le envía la información de cada lista:

foreach($data as $nomLista=>$values) {
    echo '<h2>Lista '.$nomLista.'</h2>'.PHP_EOL;
    printTable($values);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo hice un código que ordena los candidatos por listas.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Prueba de PHP</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <?php
//Conección con la base de datos
   $dbhost = 'localhost';
   $dbuser = 'root';
   $dbpass = 'root';
   $dbname = 'pruebas';
   $mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

   if($mysqli→connect_errno ) {
      printf("Connect failed: %s<br />", $mysqli→connect_error);
      exit();
   }

//Consulta de listas
   $listas = $mysqli->query("SELECT lista.nombre AS nomLista,
           lista.id AS idLista
           FROM lista ORDER BY lista.nombre");

           if ($listas->num_rows > 0) {
             while($row = $listas->fetch_assoc()) {

                 $lista = $row["idLista"];

                 printf("<h2>Lista  %s </h2>", $row["nomLista"]);
                 crearTablasPorListas($lista, $mysqli);
             }
           } else {
             printf('No record found.<br />');
           }
           mysqli_free_result($result);
           $mysqli→close();


//Funcion que genera las tablas dentro de cada lista
function crearTablasPorListas($lista, $mysqli){

  $query = "SELECT candidato.nombre AS nomCandidato,
    partido.nombre AS nomPartido
    FROM candidato
    INNER JOIN partido ON partido.id = candidato.id_partido
    INNER JOIN lista ON lista.id = candidato.id_lista
    INNER JOIN region ON region.id = candidato.id_region
    WHERE region.nombre = 'Metropolitana' AND candidato.id_lista ='".$lista."'";

  $candidato = $mysqli->query($query);

    print "<table>
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Candidato</th>
              <th>Partido</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>";




    if ($candidato->num_rows > 0) {
      while($row = $candidato->fetch_assoc()) {

          $nomCandidato = $row["nomCandidato"];
          $nomPartido = $row["nomPartido"];

          printf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>", $nomCandidato, $nomPartido);

      }
    } else {
      printf('No record found.<br />');
    }
    mysqli_free_result($candidato);

print "</tbody>
      </table>";


}
```

Usé mysqli, para la conección con mysql y las consultas

Comment: El problema de este código es que ejecutaría `N` consultas, donde `N` es el número de listas. En algunos casos esto puede afectar seriamente el rendimiento.

Comment: @aeportugal probaste el código que comparti. Yo creé una base de datos idéntica, con *Apache* lo ejecuté y obtuve un resultado optimo; siguiendo el ejemplo que publicaste. si *arroja* *error* lo reviso por si lo copié mal.